# QMainWindow how to lock dockwidgets in place

Tags: c++, qt

I want to lock the current user defined layout of my gui. My gui is a QMainWindow with a
QMainWindow as central widgets and everything else, including multiple GLWidgets as dockwidgets. So everything can be placed almost anywhere. Once the user activates the lock 
I replace the title widgets of the dockwidgets with a new QWidget. That already keeps 
them in place just fine.

Now I want to prevent the manual resizing of the widgets but still allow the automatic
resizing when the QMainWindow is changed in size. So setting the dockwidgets to fixed size
at the time of the lock is not an option, I rather need a way to hide the resize handlers
between the widgets.

Comment: i understand that 'current user defined layout' is something where the user has the possibility to change the layout the way he wants... if i am correct, i would try to get some basic layouts in the ui where the widgets snap in. so you have the size managed by them. soo long zai

Comment: Not quite what I want. I edited my question to explain what the gui is like.

Comment: ok. so the widget that replaces the `QDockWidget` should stay docked on that position where the user left it ... if so, try to use `QDockWidget::setFeatures(QDockWidget::NoDockWidgetFeatures)`to restrict the user to close/move/float the `QDockWidget`, set a layout on that and place your widget inside the dockwidget.

Comment: That's still not what I meant. When the user locks the gui I already remove the title bars of the DockWidgets fixing them in place. But it is still possible to change their sizes. I want to disable/remove the resize handler between the widgets.

Comment: ok. next try... (slowly i get a clue what you need ;) )

so i would subclass `QDockWidget` and overwrite the `QWidget::resizeEvent ( QResizeEvent * event )`.

Comment: That is a possibility but would be more complicated than what I have in mind. Like I said in the question, I want to disable manual resizing of the dockwidgets but still adjust them according to the current ratio when the size of the mainwindow changes. While that's possible to do in a resize event handler I was hoping for something simpler.

Comment: maybe this will help you ... http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qobject.html#installEventFilter ... thats the last thing that come to my mind for 'saving work' with you problem. soo long zai

Comment: why are you using dock widgets in the first place, and not a layout?

Comment: Because I want to give the user the freedom to arrange the widgets the way they want.

Comment: You will have to implement something nasty. You want to use stuff that wasn't designed for your needs.